# Como posicionar Imagenes dentro de DIV

Tags: html, css, asp

Tengo una etiqueta div y necesito que algunos objetos estén alineados a la derecha y otros a la izquierda y que se vean a la misma altura dentro de la pantalla.

Este es mi código:

```
<div align="justify">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="150px" ImageUrl="~/View/Imagen/sca.JPG" Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="190%" ForeColor="Gray" Visible="False"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
<div align="right">
    <table>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="46px" Width="306px" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#666666" Font-Size="20pt" 
                         BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="#666666" ToolTip="INGRESE APELLIDO O NOMBRE PARA LA BUSQUEDA"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="63px" Width="93px" ImageUrl="~/View/Imagen/lupa.JPG" 
                             ToolTip="BUSCAR POR APELLIDO O NOMBRE EN GRUPO SELECCIONADO" BorderWidth="0px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Y esta es la imagen de lo que espero obtener:

[image: Resultado a esperar]

*NOTA: La etiqueta y la caja de texto deben estar a la misma altura.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, **no deberías usar tablas** para crear layouts, además no logro ver cual es el comportamiento deseado para la imagen, así que haciendo modificaciones menores a tu código y aprovechando las bondades de flexbox, este sería el resultado:

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .c-left table,
.container .c-left tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="c-left">
        <table>
            <tr>  
                <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;etiqueta&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c-right">
        <table>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td ><button>boton</button></td>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias , pruebo y te comento...bueno la verdad el diseño no es mi fortaleza....gracias

Comment: De hecho esto no es diseño ;)

Comment: Muy bueno resulto bien era lo q buscaba

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes considerar aceptarla.

Answer (score 0):

Hola desconozco el alcanze del tu proyecto pero si este te lo permite puedes usar un framework que facilite tu labor como puede ser boostrap o materialize.

So exelentes para crear diseños adaptables y sus grids facilitan mucho pero mucho el trabajo.

Comment: Josue, gracias por el aporte pero infortunadamente esto no responde la pregunta, podrías dar un ejemplo relacionado directamente con el problema de Efrain?